# The limit of day reputation is not calculated correctly?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

As the graph shows, I have no downvote, and have 4 accepted answer yesterday. I have reached the limit of 200 reputation limit a day. So the total i should get is 200+15*4=260, but the graph is showed only 250.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the answers you posted yesterday was deleted. That answer had an upvote, but since it was deleted the vote doesn't count in your reputation tab.

However, since some of your other answers received upvotes past the rep cap, if you [recalculate your reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) you should see no change in your total reputation score, but I believe your reputation tab will count 10 reputation into one of those extra upvotes.

Comment: So that is what it is. Can I find my deleted answer? I can not remember I have deleted an answer.

Comment: It was deleted by another moderator, probably because people were flagging it. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9030834

Comment: you mean the author deleted his question will also cause this case?

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that the question was deleted. Looks like you won't be able to see your answer then. It doesn't seem to be very important or valuable, so you can leave it as it is.